# The ReplayingDecoder wants to collect multiple incoming messages and pass them to the next handler

Tags: netty, decoder

Below is the server side code.
Implement simple replayingDecoder to divide incoming messages into multiple pieces
I want to use it as a preprocessor for the business logic in the following Handler.

However, after the decode is done in TestReplayingDecoder, anotherHandler's channRead method is not executed
Only the channelReadComplete method is performed. Why?

Similarly, when you implement ReplayingDecode with checkPoint and state,
I have confirmed that the following handler's channelRead works well.

```
.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                        pipeline.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                        pipeline.addLast(new TestReplayingDecoder());
                        pipeline.addLast(new AnotherHandler());
                    }
                });



@Slf4j
public class TestReplayingDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<Void> {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        out.add(in.readBytes(in.readInt()));
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}



@Slf4j
@Sharable
public class AnotherHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        String msgString = (String) msg;
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(makeResponse(msg), CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
    }
}
```

log ===================

```
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1 [-:-] [id: 0x2e31ca6f, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:21103] READ: [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671]
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1 [-:-] [id: 0x2e31ca6f, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:21103] READ COMPLETE
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] REGISTERED
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] ACTIVE
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] AnotherHandler.channelActive !!
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] READ: 1024B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 32 39 36 36 41 42 41 30 37 41 52 50 30 32 30 30 |.                |
~ ~
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] TestReplayingDecoder.decode !!
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] READ: 1024B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 |                |
~ ~ 
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] TestReplayingDecoder.decode !!
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] READ: 922B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 |                |
~ ~ 
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] TestReplayingDecoder.decode !!
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] READ COMPLETE
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] AnotherHandler.channelReadComplete !!
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] WRITE: 0B
nioEventLoopGroup-3-2 [-:-] [id: 0x653410de, L:/127.0.0.1:21103 - R:/127.0.0.1:61671] FLUSH
```

Comment: What I am wondering is that the channelReadComplete of AnotherHandler is called after the decode occurs n times, is this a normal flow?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure your `channelRead(...)` method is invoked but it will cause an `ClassCastException` as you try to cast the msg to a `String` while it will be a `ByteBuf` as you produce `ByteBuf`s in your `TestReplayingDecoder`.